# Auto applying 'height' data to submenu's with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a fairly simple menu structure, one level deep, made using UL/LI's as below...

- Menu Item 1
- Menu Item 2
- Menu Item 3

  - Sub Item 1
  - Sub Item 2
  - Sub Item 3
- Menu Item 4

The menus are displayed in a vertical fashion with a roll-out on hover, in exactly the same basic format as the vertical suckerfish demos shown here: http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/example/vertical.html

What I want to do is, using jQuery, automatically apply a class to the LI of each sub menu with the corresponding height of the menu item.  For example Sub Item 1 is beside Menu Item 3, which would make it's 'height' 3.  Sub Item 2 has a 'height' of 4.  Sub Menu 2 of Menu Item 4 would have a 'height' of 5.  etc.

The reason I am doing this is the sub-menu items need to have a css style which will fit in with the background - the menu is curved - so they need to have a class applied so the styling will be correct for their height.

I am fairly sure the code required shouldn't be too large - it just needs to add a class of the style 'height1' or 'height2' etc. to each sub li, I just can't think where to start myself as my javascript skills are still a bit rudimentary!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.  Just swap out #nav with the id of your UL.  Also, this assumes a zero-indexed height (height0, height1, height2, etc.).

```
function applyHeightClasses( el, offset ){
  if(! ( offset > 0 ) ) offset = 0;

  $( el ).children( 'li' ).each( function( i ) {
    $(this).addClass( 'height' + ( offset + i ) );

    $(this).children( 'ul' ).each( function( x ) {
      applyHeightClasses( this, ( offset + i + x ) );
    });

  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  applyHeightClasses('#nav');
});
```